# react-virtualized - Is it possible to infinite scroll groups of list?

Tags: infinite-scroll, react-virtualized

After reading through the documentation, I am not sure if `react-virtualized` support this use case.

Let's say I have some data grouped by date.

```js
[
  {
    date: 'Monday',
    data: {
      item1: "item1",
      item2: "item2",
      item3: "item3",
      // and more ..
    }
  },
  {
    date: "Tuesday",
    data: {
      item1: "item1",
      item2: "item2",
      item3: "item3",
      // and more ..
    }
  }
]
```

Is it possible to use `react-virtualized` with `InfiniteLoader` and `List` to render something like this:

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <div class="day">Monday</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <!-- and more... -->
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="day">Tuesday</div>
    <div>item1</div>
    <div>item2</div>
    <div>item3</div>
    <!-- and more... -->
  </div>
</div>
```

or does the markup has to be flat?

Answer (score 1):

The markup doesn't have to be flat, so long as there's only 1 root node per row.

For example, check out [this demo](https://rawgit.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/master/playground/tree.html) (source [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/playground/tree.js)). Each react-virtualized row in this tree view contains 1-to-many children, depending on whether it's been expanded.